# how to create a simple client server application in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, client-server

I would like to create a client server application in WPF. I dont know if this application is as same as console application. Because there is XAML part in WPF. That's why I'm asking here.

Can you give some sample code for this application ?

I will send some text or file from one machine to another machine, I think I should run server part in other machine and client part in my machine? but first I want to try both in my machine.

Thank you.

Comment: sorry do you want to build your "server"-part inside a WPF application or just the client? And no this is not quite the same as a console application and you might want to learn the basics of WPF first (and then you will still have to learn WCF or something similar if you want communication between applications/machines)

Comment: Here you can find a sample application using WPF/WCF for communication between chat-applications: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21264/WPF-WCF-Chat-Application-Simplified-via-P2P

Comment: I wish SO would prevent downvoting of "novice"-questions without giving a reason - will upvote just for this reason...

Comment: @phoog's answer is a pretty good summary of why this is collecting downvotes. To paraphrase the tooltip describing the purpose of the Downvote button, this question doesn't show any research effort. It is unclear, and not useful.

Comment: I want to build client app in WPF and server app in console. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the third paragraph, when developing client-server applications, it is common to debug both the client and the server on the same machine.  If you're using Visual Studio, you can do this by creating the client and server applications as separate projects in the same solution.

Sample code for an entire client-server application is beyond the scope of a stackoverflow question or answer; you'd do better to ask a single question focusing on a specific aspect of a problem you're currently facing.  Once you've resolved that, return to the site and ask a question about the next problem.

Also, questions that ask "how can I learn something to help me solve this problem" are generally received far more favorably than questions that ask "please solve my problem for me."

Answer (score 0):

For simplified implementation you will need [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd939784) which will makes the communication between client server easier.  There are lot of good tutorials online on [WCF/WPF](https://www.google.com/search?q=wcf%20wpf%20sample%20apps&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&safe=active).